# "Vous êtes tout ce que je pensais que vous soyez."

Tags: subjonctif

In the phrase above (heard on a French TV show), why is the final verb in the subjunctive? I would have guessed the sentence would read "Vous êtes tout ce que je pensais que vous seriez."

Merci !

Edit: Let me clarify the intent/context of the sentence: "You are everything I thought you would be." One character says it upon meeting another for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence with "soyez" is not correct. As you guessed it, the author meant "*you are all what I thought you will/would become*".

For a better understanding, the sentence may be replaced by the following:

> Vous êtes celui que je pensais que vous deviendriez.

The use of the "conditionnel" (not the subjonctive) for the final verb "seriez" is correct. However, the original formulation (with *soyez*) or the modified one (with *seriez*) are so far-fetched that I don't imagine most French speakers using them.

```
 EDIT 1
```

As mentionned in @AlexandreP.Levasseur comment, the author may have meant:

> Vous êtes tout ce que je pensais que vous **étiez**.

What can be translated to "You are all what I thought you were".

To answer to Alexandre, both sentences with "etiez" or "seriez" are not shocking: I just think that almost none native speaker will use such formulations to convey the idea.

```
 EDIT 2
```

To translate "You are everything I thought you would be", on pourrait dire:

> Vous êtes [vraiment] tel que je l'imaginais.

Comment: That is an incorrect understanding of the original sentence. Though the original formulation is not grammatically correct, I would not be shocked to hear it or its more correct "étiez".

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur - Even if your understanding is a possibility, you cannot claim that the OP understanding (that is also mine) is incorrect. However, I edited my post to take your comment into account.

Comment: I said your understanding was faulty, not OP's. As for the original sentence... I am a native French speaker and I can assure you that both versions of the sentence ("étiez" / "seriez") would flow perfectly fine in a conversation. Using "deviendriez" is not the original meaning intended, as confirmed by OP's edit.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur - Chacun ses opinions! J'ai du mal à croire qu'on puisse employer un style aussi lourd. (*ma langue maternelle est aussi le Français*).

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way:

«Je pensais que vous étiez aimable» is correct.

«Vous êtes ce que je pensais que vous étiez» is just as correct.

Comment: This is a good method to a analyse the problem. But, note that "Je pensais que vous *seriez* aimable» is perfectly correct as well.

Comment: Oui mais cela ne veut pas dire la même chose. Au présent on dit: «Je pense que l'hiver sera long.» Phrase qui au passé donne: «Je pensais que l'hiver serait long». Phrase qui à son tour a un sens bien différent de: «Je pensais que l'hiver était long.»

Answer (score 0):

Votre analyse paraît exacte. La forme semble incorrecte.

Les formes suivantes paraissent possibles dont la vôtre :

- tout ce que je pensais que vous étiez : même temps: simultanéité avec certitude

**- tout ce que je pensais que vous seriez: futur dans le passé avec ou sans doute**

- tout ce que je pensais que vous fussiez: même temps avec un doute
- tout ce que je pensais que vous eussiez été: passé dans le passé avec un doute
- tout ce que je pensais que vous êtes: présent intemporel avec une certitude

Comment: Le subjonctif va souvent de pair avec des constructions qui expriment le doute, mais il n'exprime jamais le doute de lui-même, il s'agit là d'une idée fausse. Il n'y a aucune raison de l'utiliser, ni au présent ni au passé. *Eussiez été* peut aussi être employé comme un conditionel, mais avec une principale au présent ça ne marche pas.